# Light Pollution: what is the difference between artificial brightness and brightness and SQM

Tags: light-pollution

At [this light pollution map](https://www.lightpollutionmap.info/#zoom=6.86&lat=34.1895&lon=-114.9452&layers=B0FFFFFFTFFFFFFFFFF) they show degrees of light pollution but they have 3 numbers to quantify light pollution and they do not explain in the help section what the numbers mean:

The numbers are [SQM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sky_quality_meter), brightness and artificial brightness.  I get that for the last two the lower the better for viewing stars, but I can't figure out if brightness perhaps includes artificial brightness.

[image: Screen shot of the legend]

Comment: I added the screenshot which shows what I guess what you are talking about. Feel free to replace it, if you are talking about something else.

Comment: @JamesK Since you commented on [my question about light pollution](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/40632/how-many-streetlights-should-we-turn-off-to-decrease-light-on-the-ground-by-abou) I guess you might be able to help bobsmith76

Comment: Does https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/21484/in-an-area-with-lots-of-light-pollution-which-clear-sky-clock-parameter-is-most help you?

Comment: No, I saw the website cleardarksky.com and it's too confusing.