# Different approaches to quantify light pollution on a given location on Earth?

Tags: satellite, light-pollution, observational-astronomy

The question [Light Pollution: what is the difference between artificial brightness and brightness and SQM](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/40967/light-pollution-what-is-the-difference-between-artificial-brightness-and-bright#comment83719_40967) made me wonder which different ways exist to **directly and indirectly quantify [light pollution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light_pollution) at a given location on the Earth's surface**? The obvious sources like Wikipedia etc. did not satisfiy my curiosity.

What I came up so far as a list of different methods is the following:

1. Look what you can observe with naked eye and use the [Bortle scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bortle_scale).
2. Use a [Sky quality meter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sky_quality_meter) of any kind and measure [luminance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luminance).
3. Use the measurements of a [pyranometer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyranometer) of your friendly metereologist or of an [automatic weather station](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_weather_station) nearby and callibrate how many ${\rm W}/{\rm m}^2$ correspond to what value on the Bortle scale.
4. Use satellite data of any kind to obtain an approximate

   - If your urban area is bright enough, you could see that and in the visible spectrum of any weather satellite, and deduce a lower bound, i.e. how bright it must be at least on the ground.
   - The [US's DOD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_Department_of_Defense) might release maps from the [Defense Metorological Satellite Program](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defense_Meteorological_Satellite_Program) every now and then.

I am sure this list is not exhaustive - which other approaches am I missing?